# Jquery function not called when called on modal pop up submit button in partial view in ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call jquery function on Modal popup submit button, which is in partial view but the function is not called if that button is in partial view, it is only called when i put my modal pop up in main view. How to solve this issue... Please help .. Thanks

Index.cshtml

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", null, null, new { id = "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-small btn-info" })
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $('#btnCreate').click(function () {
                alert("function called");
                $('.modal-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                    $('#ShowModalDialog').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: true
                    }, 'show');
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Useremail').blur(function () {
                alert("func called");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Home/Search',
                    data: "{'searchString':'" + document.getElementById('Useremail').value + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Record found");
                    },
                    error: function () { alert("record not found"); }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id='ShowModalDialog' class='modal fade in'>
        <div class='modal-dialog'>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

_Create.cshtml PartialView

```
@model MvcTwitterBootstrap.Models.UserDetail
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            ×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">
            Registration</h3>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "modal-form" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserEmail)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserEmail, new { @id = "Useremail" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserEmail)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserPassword)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserPassword, new { id = "Userpassword" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserPassword)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnsubmit">
                Save</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for items that are added to the form after load you need to put the function on the document instead of the item

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnCreate', function(){
    //code
});
```

the other option would be to put all of the click events in a function

```
function LoadScript(){
    //jquery code here
}
```

and then call that function after the partial is loaded

```
$('#divContent').html(result);
LoadScript();
```